# In Sitecore Personalize, what is the difference between experiences and experiments?

Tags: personalization, sitecore-personalize

I want to show some personalized content to customers using `Sitecore Personalize`. How can I tell whether I should be setting up an experience or an experiment? Both an experience and an experiment seem to have the same functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Experiments are for running AB tests, in which a variant is compared against a control group. Experiences are for always on personalisation or operational use cases.

In practical terms, when an experiment is created:

1. a control group is automatically created by the platform
2. the sample size can be calculated in the details tab, this sample size is used to determine when the experiment is complete and the performance results can be interpreted.

When an experience is created:

1. there is no control group automatically created
2. there is no sample size to be calculated as there is no test running